# How does the C/C++ extension of Visual Studio Code find the default compiler?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started a project and I created my `c_cpp_properties.json` file. I was quite surprised to find that the contents of the file showed a compiler by default:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\DiaSemi\\SmartSnippetsStudio\\Tools\\mingw64_targeting32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

I was wondering how did it find that particular `gcc.exe` path, as even though it's installed in my computer, I've never used it, and if I had, I would have done it from the Dialog Semi IDE, not Visual Studio Code and if I had ever set a default compiler, that's probably the last one I would have chosen. I checked the settings, and for the life of me, I can't find any "default compiler" setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code found it through a very odd include in my general path in Windows. After deleting it, new projects don't have a default compiler path.